# Using ES6 import module aliases with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, module, create-react-app

In Angular, it's pretty straightforward to rewrite your imports, so that something like this:

```
import { ProgressBar } from '../../common';
```

becomes this:

```
import { ProgressBar } from '@common';
```

Is this possible in react nowadays with `create-react-app`? I have done a lot of reading, and it seems I have one of these options:

- eject my app and fiddle with the config directly; or
- install `cracro` or some other `create-react-app` hack

Is there a third? Since I very strongly don't want to do either of these?

Bonus points: will my JetBrains IDE understand these module aliases when refactoring/optimising imports?

Comment: You can set that in `compilerOptions` inside `paths` in your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Well, I had partial success. That works for the IDE – but on compiling, it falls over. I saw a post suggesting modifying package.json too, but this didn't really work.